# query where delete requires condition before inserting into new table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to get solution for following query, if you can give me hint that would be great.

I have following table

```
MainId      SubId      Code
A01         r01        pre1
A01         r02        pre1
A01         s01        post1
A01         s02        post1
A01         s03        post1
A02         s04        post1
A02         s05        post1
A02         s06        post1
A03         r05        pre1
A03         r06        pre1
```

expected result:

```
MainId      SubId   Code
A01         s01     post1
A01         s02     post1
A01         s03     post1
A02         s04     post1
A02         s05     post1
A02         s06     post1
A03         r05     pre1
A03         r06     pre1
```

I want to delete all records where main id has pre1 but condition is main id must meet both pre1 and POST1 values.

So, for an example if you see above A01 has both pre1 and post1 means that case is completed and we don't need any more records with pre1, so I want to delete them.

if MAINID has only pre1 or post1, then leave it as it is.

After this or simultaneously I want to transfer result set into new table also.

Comment: can there be only "pre1" and "post1" in the code?

Comment: it looks like it deleted everything, i still need to keep post1  vaues of the same mainid for which you are deleting pre1 values.

Comment: right, I didn't understand your requirement well at first. Hope you're enclosing everything you read on SO in BEGIN TRAN / ROLLBACK!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try out this, it should do what you want:

```
DELETE FROM #TEMP   
WHERE CODE = 'PRE1'   
AND MAIN_ID IN (    
SELECT MAIN_ID FROM #TEMP
WHERE CODE = 'POST1')
```

Comment: Yes this one is also a solution

Comment: Thanks, hope if helps. Please upvote/accept the answer.

Comment: it says I need to earned 15 reputation or something.

Answer (score 2):

I think this should work:

```
DELETE yourTable
WHERE Code = 'pre1'
AND   MainId IN (SELECT MainId FROM yourTable WHERE Code = 'post1')
```

Comment: Thanks peter, this is the one.

Comment: If it helped, then please also Accept the answer: http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers